# Foam sealant around plumbing fixtures in new home, okay to keep as is and/or how should I make this look more finished?

Tags: walls, foam

[image]We moved not too long ago and there's this foam (not sure if this might be spray foam?) sealing around several plumbing fixtures (like under the kitchen sink in the picture below) as well as a handful of other openings in the wall.

When we did the home inspection this wasn't brought up as a concern but wondering if it's okay to be left as is? Any tips on how to finish these areas to make them look more aesthetically pleasing?[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Are these in view? if not, leave them it's fine

My strategy to "finish over" foam is to gently prod it back into the gap which will make it denser. Stabilise the perimeter of the form with acrylic adhesive/hybrid sealant (ie. glue the blob of foam to the perimeter of the hole) to make sure it's stable and won't move, a thin skin of sealant over the surface to get a good bond and then fill on top.